# In shader intBitsToFloat and floatBitsToInt

Tags: opengl, bit-manipulation, glsl

So this issue I'm running into is lack of knowledge, I need to be in the glsl 120 (OpenGL 2.1) which locks the software down heavily, Essentially I need many of the features from 440 shaders in 120, using shader5 on supported hardware which covers it just fine, however on shader4 for mac and other things IE mesa I need to do a lot of functions myself. But the ones that keep nagging me are my bit related functions, I'm very bad at tracking bits so any help would be lovely. The largest function I'm having issues on is intBitsToFloat and floatBitsToInt, I've tried a few things but to no success.

```
int floatToIntBitst(float a){
    //Nan
    if(a != a) return 0x7fc00000;

    //-0
    if (a == 0.0) return  (1.0 / a == -1.0/0.0 ) ? 0x80000000 : 0;

    bool neg = false;
    if (a < 0.0) {
        neg = true;
        a = -a;
    }

    if (isinf(a)) {
        return neg ? 0xff800000 : 0x7f800000;
    }

    int exp = ((a >> 52) & 0x7ff) - 1023;
    int mantissa = (a & 0xffffffff) >> 29;
    if (exp <= -127) {
        mantissa = (0x800000 | mantissa) >> (-127 - exp + 1);
        exp = -127;
    }
    int bits = negative?2147483648: 0;
    bits |= (exp + 127) << 23;
    bits |= mantissa;

    return bits;
}
```

some of my other functions, any feedback would be appreciated

bitfieldReverse

```
int bitfieldReverse(int x) {
    x = ((x & 0x55555555) << 1) | ((x & 0xAAAAAAAA) >> 1);
    x = ((x & 0x33333333) << 2) | ((x & 0xCCCCCCCC) >> 2);
    x = ((x & 0x0F0F0F0F) << 4) | ((x & 0xF0F0F0F0) >> 4);
    x = ((x & 0x00FF00FF) << 8) | ((x & 0xFF00FF00) >> 8);
    x = ((x & 0x0000FFFF) << 16) | ((x & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
    return x;
}
```

I have all variations, if something needs to change for uints let me know.

LSB and MSB

```
int   findLSB(int x  ) { return x&-x; }

int findMSB(int x) {
    x |= (x >> 1);
    x |= (x >> 2);
    x |= (x >> 4);
    x |= (x >> 8);
    x |= (x >> 16);
    return (x & ~(x >> 1));
}
```

Same goes for these

bitCount

```
int bitCount(int a) {
    a = (a & 0x55555555) + ((a >>  1) & 0x55555555); 
    a = (a & 0x33333333) + ((a >>  2) & 0x33333333); 
    a = (a + (a >> 4)) & 0x0f0f0f0f; 
    a = (a + (a >> 8)); 
    a = (a + (a >> 16)); 
    return a & 0xff;
}
```

Comment: you cannot really do `floatToIntBitst` without proper hardware support. NaNs can include a payload which is inaccessible to normal arithmetic operators, but you still need to extract it for a proper `IntBitsToFloat<->floatToIntBits` roundtriy.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware that doesn't offer GL 3.0+ is almost always hardware that also doesn't have integers as a type distinct from `float`. As such, all of your `int`s are really `float`s in disguise. Which means that they must live with the ranges and restrictions of a `float`.

Because of this, you cannot effectively do the kind of bit-manipulation you're trying on such hardware.

Comment: This would be true, except the hardware is 3.0+, it's complicated why the context is 120, but it's running shader4 for macs which is built off 330 compat. https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/gpu_shader4.txt

Comment: @dotModded: But... those functions are part of GLSL 3.30. So why are you bothering to re-implement what you clearly have access to? If you have access to 3.30, then you have access to the [ARB_shader_bit_encoding](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_bit_encoding.txt) extension. So if you require ARB_gpu_shader4, you also ought to be able to require that extension as well.

Comment: Because of mac drivers ARB_shader_bit_encoding is not included in their legacy drivers it makes it impossible for macs.